# Problema de resolución con netbeans 11

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-11

Tengo un problema con la resolución con la aplicación de NeatBeans 11 apache. 
Este se ve totalmente pixeleado al momento de trabajar con el. Lo e intentado reparar de todas formas y aún no encuentro la forma adecuada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez deberías de usar Coolbeans en su lugar, tiene mejor resolución y está basado en el mismo código base.

Comment: [tag:coolbeans]

Comment: @Ruslan López La verdad me pasa exactamente lo mismo, se ve muy pixeleado...

Comment: En Opciones de rendimiento (de tu windows ) en que opcion tienes seleccionada? prueba ingrensando a una carpeta comun , luego clic derecho en este equipo , luego configuracion avanzada del sistema , luego en renidimiento y selecciona la opcion de dejar que windows elija Esto en el caso que hayas elegido otra opcion , si esto no te soluciona el problema no sabria por mi parte
espero lo soluciones